# fineuploader s3 signature generation .net - response does not include base64 encoded policy

Tags: base64, fine-uploader

Passing policy from fineuploader. The policy is:

```
{
    "expiration": "2015-11-07T20:18:13.326Z",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "acl": "private"
        },
        {
            "bucket": "fine-upload-test"
        },
        {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        {
            "success_action_status": "200"
        },
        {
            "key": "c94d36ee-19eb-49e8-ac30-760b29982391.txt"
        },
        {
            "x-amz-meta-qqfilename": "adstats.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

Processing using .net and returning the following json response:

```
{
    "d": "{ \"signature\":\"305A5A46646B522B324B6B6A6D766B314C717072707A49733362633D\", \"policy\":\"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0wN1QyMDoxODoxMy4zMjZaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYWNsIjoicHJpdmF0ZSJ9LHsiYnVja2V0IjoiZmluZS11cGxvYWQtdGVzdCJ9LHsiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIjoidGV4dC9wbGFpbiJ9LHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fc3RhdHVzIjoiMjAwIn0seyJrZXkiOiJjOTRkMzZlZS0xOWViLTQ5ZTgtYWMzMC03NjBiMjk5ODIzOTEudHh0In0seyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXFxZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJhZHN0YXRzLnR4dCJ9XX0=\"}"
}
```

Error is "Response does not include the base 64 encoded policy!"

I have checked the base64 encoded "policy" and it decodes to the exact policy being passed in.
Please, what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a valid response. Fine Uploader S3 expects you to return a flat JSON response with two properties: signature and policy. Instead, you are returning a JSON response with a "d" property that itself contains signature and policy properties. You can see this clearly in the response pasted into your question.

Comment: Yes, .net (after 3.5) wraps json response in the {b. Nothing I can do about that. Is there a fix in the fineuploader js that will allow the use of the json document as is?